# How to send Custom Headers using PHP Gouttee

Tags: php, curl, goutte

I am trying to scrape a site that actually block Bots.

I have this code in PHP cURL to get away with blockage.

```
$headers = array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding: zip, deflate, sdch'
    , 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8'
    , 'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'User-Agent:' . $user_agents[array_rand($user_agents)]
);
curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($curl_init);
```

It works well.

But I am using [PHP Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte), I want to generate same request using this library

```
$headers2 = array(
    'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'zip, deflate, sdch'
    , 'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
    , 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=0',
    'User-Agent' => $user_agents[array_rand($user_agents)]
);
$client = new Client();

foreach ($headers2 as $key => $v) {
    $client->setHeader($key, $v);
}
$resp = $client->request('GET', $url);
echo $resp->html();
```

But using this code I get blocked from the site I am scraping.

I want to know how can I use Gouttee to properly use Headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to check result of Goutte

```
$status_code = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();
echo $status_code;
```

This is source code I had success with Guzzle
In index.php

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<?php
    $begin = microtime(true);
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    require 'helpers/helper.php';
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://www.yellowpages.com.au',
        'cookies' => true,
        'headers' =>  [
            'Accept'          => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'zip, deflate, sdch', 
            'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 
            'Cache-Control'   => 'max-age=0',
            'User-Agent'      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
        ]
    ]);
    $helper = new Helper($client);
    $mostViewed = $helper->getPageTest();
?>
<html>
```

In helper.php file

```
<?php
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
class Helper{
    protected $client;
    protected $totalPages;
    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client){
        $this->client       = $client;
        $this->totalPages   = 3;
    }
    public function query()
    {
        $queries = array(
            'clue'  => 'Builders',
            'locationClue'  => 'Sydney%2C+2000',
            'mappable' => 'true',
            'selectedViewMode' => 'list'
        );
        // print_r($queries);
        return $this->client->get('search/listings', array('query' => $queries));
    }
    public function getPageTest()
    {
        $responses = $this->query();
        $html = $responses->getBody()->getContents();
        echo $html;
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

And result I got

[image]

Hope this helpful!!!

Comment: http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=Builders&locationClue=Sydney%2C+2000&mappable=true&selectedViewMode=list  this is URL

Comment: Hi bro, you can use Guzzle replace for Goutte in this case? I had success with Guzzle

Comment: I had update my source code working well with Guzzle. It's similar with Goutte.

Comment: UPVOTED... i will check this code... also do you know how to use proxy with Goutte? I have tried `client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/' . CURLOPT_PROXY, '186.170.31.134:8080');` but it is giving me error `Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: do you know how to set Cookie file path and cURL options array in Goutte?

Comment: You can using Guzzle? I know Guzzle

Comment: I mean Goutte and Guzzle are same?

Comment: Send me your content of cookies.

Comment: Page not found bro